# Python inspect.getmembers does not return all members?

Tags: python, torch

Is this a bug in inspect.getmembers, or is this the expected behavior?

```
torch.bmm in inspect.getmembers(torch)
False
```

Comment: Print out what `inspect.getmembers` returns, or look at the docs, and it should be clear why this is false.

Comment: Is it illegal here to get Tesla's email? AKA:Adam Miller?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Tesla's email?

Comment: I need your email. We used to room together in Summerville

Comment: Oh, thank you. Is there a way to instant message you on here? I'm just not sure I remember you.

Comment: no..you can email me at sentienticity@protonmail.com if the arch linux admins don't delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug; this is [`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) doing exactly what it's documented to do:

> Return all the members of an object in a list of (name, value) pairs sorted by name…

So, `('bmm', torch.bmm)` might be in such a list, but `torch.bmm` won't.

---

If you want to know if `torch.bmm` is a member of `torch`… well, you already *know* that it is, or `torch.bmm` would have raised an `AttributeError`. But you can search the second (value) part of each pair:

```
any(member == torch.bmm for name, member in inspect.getmembers(torch))
```

… or you can turn the list into a dict and search it:

```
torch.bmm in dict(inspect.getmembers(torch)).values()
```

---

But, again, the fact that `torch.bmm` didn't raise an exception is already enough to tell you that it exists. If you want to handle the possibility that it doesn't, any checking you do after getting that exception is too late; you just want to handle the exception:

```
try:
    torch.bmm
except AttributeError:
    # whatever you wanted to do if it doesn't exist
else:
    # whatever you wanted to do with torch.bmm
```

Comment: >>> torch.bmm in dict(inspect.getmembers(torch)).values()
True

It looked like it was missing when I reviewed the list.